# Fetch Core Data as comma separated list

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, swift4

I realise that I am missing something simple but as a Swift newbie I am going around in circles & would appreciate a pointer as to what I am doing wrong?!

I have a Core Data Entity called "Numbers" with an attribute (Int16) called "userNumbers". I am fetching the results like:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Numbers")
    //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age = %@", "12")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
         let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print("\(data.value(forKey: "userNumbers") as! Int16)")
        }

    } catch {            
        print("Failed")
    }
```

The result in my console is:

12

13

18

19

21

I need to know how to make this a comma separated list so I can use it in an array. Essentially I need the return to be: 12,13,18,19,21

Everything I try seems to be wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a more specific fetch request to get a distinct result type

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Numbers>(entityName: "Numbers")
```

A *comma separated list* is not possible because the type of `userNumbers` is numeric.

You can `map` the result to an array of `Int16` with

```
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request) // the type is [Numbers]
    let numberArray = result.map{$0.userNumbers}
    print(numberArray)
}
```

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated